# React Conditionally show image using switch statement not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement

Hello I'm trying to show different hangman picture according to the value of props.lives.

```
import React from 'react';
import one from '../images/one.png';
import two from '../images/two.png';
import three from '../images/three.png';
import four from '../images/four.png';
import five from '../images/five.png';
import six from '../images/six.png';
import seven from '../images/seven.png';
import eight from '../images/eight.png';
import nine from '../images/nine.png';
import ten from '../images/ten.png';
import eleven from '../images/eleven.png';
import twelve from '../images/twelve.png';

const hangman = (props) => {
    // const picture = new Array(props.lives).map(
    //     (_,i) => ( <span>{i}</span> )
    // );

    // const picture = [ ...Array(props.lives) ].map(
    //     (_,i) => ( <span key={i}>{++i}</span> )
    // );

    let hangmanImage = null;

    switch (props.lives)
    {
        case 11:
            hangmanImage={one};
            break;
        case 10:
            hangmanImage={two};
            break;
        case 9:
            hangmanImage={three};
            break;
        case 8:
            hangmanImage={four};
            break;
        case 7:
            hangmanImage={five};
            break;
        case 6:
            hangmanImage={six};
            break;
        case 5:
            hangmanImage = {seven};
            break;
        case 4:
            hangmanImage = {eight};
            break;
        case 3:
            hangmanImage = {nine};
            break;
        case 2:
            hangmanImage = {ten};
            break;
        case 1:
            hangmanImage = {eleven};
            break;
        case 0:
            hangmanImage = {twelve};
            break;  
        default:
            hangmanImage = null;
    }

    return (
        <img src={hangmanImage} />
    );
}

export default hangman;
```

If I do for example,

```
return (
   <img src={three} />
}
```

This shows the image. But not when I do,

```
return (
   <img src={hangmanImage} />
}
```

I get broken image shown. By the way, props.lives is set to 12 initially but decremented by parent component if a wrong letter is played inside game.

I'm suspecting something's wrong with logic inside switch? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried hangmanImage=one; instead of hangmanImage={one};?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have extra braces in your switch statement; you should just assign the images into your `hangmanImage` variable:

```
switch (props.lives) {
  case 11:
    hangmanImage = one;
    break;
  case 10:
    hangmanImage = two;
    break;
  case 9:
    hangmanImage = three;
    break;
  ...
}
```

Comment: @logan if this solution helped you please mark it as correct one so people know the question has been answered

Answer (score 1):

I believe your code can be shorter like this.

Furthermore, you should use `state` when you control the render() thing.

```
import React from 'react';
import one from '../images/one.png';
import two from '../images/two.png';
import three from '../images/three.png';
import four from '../images/four.png';
import five from '../images/five.png';
import six from '../images/six.png';
import seven from '../images/seven.png';
import eight from '../images/eight.png';
import nine from '../images/nine.png';
import ten from '../images/ten.png';
import eleven from '../images/eleven.png';
import twelve from '../images/twelve.png';

const imgs = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, eleven, twelve].reverse();
const hangman = (props) => {
    const [hangmanImage, setHangmenImage] = React.useState(null);
    React.useEffect(()=>{
      props.lives && setHangmanImage(imgs[props.lives]);
    },[props.lives]);


    return (
        <img src={hangmanImage} />
    );
}

export default hangman;
```